# How to override event and still preform the old one?

Tags: javascript, oop, events, dom-events

I'm looking for override event and still preform it's actions.

Meaning something like this:

```
var oldOnError = window.onerror;
window.onerror = function(msg, url, line) {
 oldOnError();
};
```

Now this will get executed **however**, `onerror` event could accept several arguments and I don't and can't know which are there.

So :

- Is there a simple solution for this?
- If not, how can i know what parameters `oldOnError` expecting to get?

Comment: Can  you use jQuery or similar?

Comment: Does it need to work in old browsers like IE8?

Comment: Well, all browsers that support window.onerror, so yes.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a option to just add another event listener to the error event?

Comment: I need that event to be executed last no matter what, and this seemed like a way to insure that and with adding an event i guess it's set by ordered as FIFO. can i control the order with `addEventListener`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use addEventListener()

```
var listener = function(msg, url, line) {
 // your code
};

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('error', listener, false);
} else if ( window.attachEvent ) { // for versions previous to IE9
    window.attachEvent( 'onerror', listener );
}
```

That way you do not override existing event listeners.

The other thing to note is that even though you specify 3 arguments your function is passed an event object when called. So really your function should be defined as follows.

```
var listener = function( event ) {
    // your code
}
```

Have a look at the MDN site [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) for more information

Comment: in what order will they be executed? order of input? can i control that order?

Comment: @eric.itzhak the `onerror` happens first, its what is being listened for. Once it fires then the `listener` function is fired.

Comment: Perfect then, did not know that. Thank you very much Bruno and ryan!

Comment: The signature is `"error"`, not `"onerror"` and this doesn't work in browsers like IE8

Comment: @Esailija so what can i for browsers like IE8? and will this code create an exception in those browsers?

Comment: @eric.itzhak I was commenting the first revision of this answer. It will work in IE8 if you use `window.attachEvent( 'onerror', listener );`, note that in `attachEvent` the event names are prefixed with `"on"` and not in `.addEventListener`

Comment: Let me get this straight, so in this code i should change to `onerror` for `attachEvent`? and this will work up to ie7 and 6?

Comment: @eric.itzhak yes I have fixed the answer in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do would be to use the apply method and the arguments variable:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

```
var oldOnError = window.onerror;
window.onerror = function(msg, url, line) {
    oldOnError.apply(window, arguments);
};
```

But as @Bruno says, only one argument should be passed to the handler anyway (the event).